# Grails render string newline in popup window

Tags: string, grails, render, popupwindow

I want to render a string with newline (\n) in my popup window. What happen is that it neglects to perform newline. My string "sample \n content" is displayed as sample content.

I want it to be displayed like this:

sample
content

Comment: is it for text output, or HTML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML does not understand

```
\n
```

i.e newline. You can solve the purpose using

```
<br/>
```

tag.

e.g.,

```
"Sample <br/> Data"
```

Enjoy..